# Prove $\{Z=0\}\subset\limsup\limits_{n}\{X_n<\epsilon\}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be independent real random variables, with values in $(0,\infty)$. Consider the random variable $Z(w):=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n(w)$. Prove that for every fixed $\epsilon>0$ the following inclusion holds.
>
> $$\{Z=0\}\subset\limsup\limits_{n}\{X_n<\epsilon\}$$

My Attempt:

$\displaystyle\{Z=0\}=\{w:\inf_nX_n=0\}=\bigcap\limits_{n\ge 1}\bigcup\limits_{k\ge 1}\{X_k\le\frac1n\}\subset\bigcap\limits_n^{\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil}\bigcup\limits_{k\ge 1}\{X_k\le\frac1n\}\subset\limsup\limits_{n}\{X_n<\epsilon\}$

Is that correct ?

Comment: I am ready to believe that you are actually asked to show that, for every positive $\varepsilon$, $$\{Z=0\}\subseteq\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\{X_n\leqslant\varepsilon\}.$$ May I suggest to check your notes?

Comment: @Did Davide Giraudo did it excellent. I saw my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Finally... you decide to replace the faulty $\{\limsup X_n\leqslant\varepsilon\}$ by the correct $\limsup\{X_n\geqslant\varepsilon\}$. Of course, this is not very courteous to the answer already posted, which becomes offtopic, but since you (mysteriously) already accepted it some time ago, I guess one could say all is well. Not sure all this confusion makes for a very helpful MSE page though.

Comment: I agree Did's comments. You should have pinged my  (and I should have answered to the good question).

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Was it a terrible mistake ? or does it have an other meaning, if $\limsup$ is in the bracket ?

Comment: Hmmm. So, you still fail to get that these are completely different objects (the point of my first comment, actually). Well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A_s:=\bigcup_{k\geqslant 1}\{X_k\leqslant s\}$. Since $A_s\subset A_t$ if $s\lt t$, we have 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\varepsilon^{-1}}A_{1/n}=A_\varepsilon$$
which is not contained in $\limsup_n\{ X_n\leqslant\varepsilon\}$.

However, we can notice that the equality
$$\{Z=0\}=\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{j\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{l\geqslant j}\left\{X_l\leqslant \frac 1n\right\}$$
holds because $X_k(\omega)$ is positive for any $\omega$. Then we reduce the intersection over $n\geqslant 1$ to $n\leqslant 1/\varepsilon$.